# How do I shift all the TOC references one page forward?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I have the page numbering starting on page 2, which is labeled in the PDF as page 1. Therefore, 'Section A' falls on page 2, but the TOC sees it as page 1, and thus sends me to page 1 rather than page 2. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\label{toc}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{A section}

\clearpage

\section{B section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which page number should your page with TOC have? No number in the footer? At the moment your first page with TOC has number 1, and your section a also has the printed page number 1 (but is second page in pdf.  Two pages 1 in a pdf like in your document is a problem for `hyperref` ...

Comment: I’ve tried your example and the hyperlinks worked correctly.  By any chance, are you experimenting problems with the index?  In any case, try saying `\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using this, if I've well understood:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\label{toc}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\section{A section}

\clearpage

\section{B section}

\end{document}
```

[image]